# Angular 2 Childroute not resolved

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I've the following route definition in a angular 2 test app

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path:'app/projects/:id',component:ProjectDetailComponent, pathMatch:'full',
            children:[
              { path:'',component:ProjectDetailOverviewComponent},
              { path:'settings',component:ProjectSettingsComponent},                
            ]
           },
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' },  
    ])
```

This works fine as the call to `{host}/app/projects/2321` works.

But when i call `{host}/app/projects/2321/settings` i get redirected to my default route.

The html of the views are all nearly empty. the ProjectDetailComponent only contains the `<router-outlet>` and the other views only contain a simple string.

what am I missing?

Comment: is the error stating "too much recursion" ?

Comment: no errors in console

Answer (score 1):

When you call `{host}/app/projects/2321/settings` i think its matching to first route which is mapped to component `ProjectDetailOverviewComponent` so try to check by changing your route configuration as below :

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{
  path: 'app/projects/:id',
  component: ProjectDetailComponent,
  children: [
          { path:'',component:ProjectDetailOverviewComponent, pathMatch:'full'},
          { path:'settings',component:ProjectSettingsComponent},                
        ]
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' },  
])
```

Comment: check by removing `pathMatch:'full',` from main `app/projects/:id` route config.

Comment: yes thats it, and thinking about it it is just logical. the route wasn'T matched as it wasn't exact.